# How to get timestamp from a String like "2017-08-30T06:40:00.000+00:00" in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, string, swift3, nsdatecomponents, dateformatter

[image]

consider the string like "2017-08-30T06:40:00.000+00:00"
1 - How to convert this string into timestamp 
2 - How to group this value into time slots (for eg, if the value is time = 2:30 PM, it will be grouped into the slot of 2pm to 3pm)

Comment: what is so wrong about the question?

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: @NehaGupta My question is how to do this? I don't understand, I am getting an array of strings from my backend in the above mentioned format, I have to group them into time slots of 1-1 hour

Comment: It is very simple what have you tried ?

Comment: "yyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss" @DeepakrajMurugesan

Comment: @Moritz I appreciate your advice, but I have also asked another question of how can dates be grouped in 1 hour gap, People just seem to down vote without reading FULL description.

Answer (score -1):

I will help you with an idea in objective C try converting to the swift, If not you can ask me. I will help you out with the right code. Write a function like this generically and use it in the places wherever you wanted to convert the date format.

```
+ (NSString*)dateFormatConv:(NSString *)givenFormat DateValue:(NSString*)dateString needFormat:(NSString *)reqFormat LabelName:(UILabel *)lbl{
    NSString *myDateString = dateString;

    NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [DateFormatter setDateFormat:givenFormat];

    NSDate *date = [DateFormatter dateFromString:myDateString];
    [DateFormatter setDateFormat:reqFormat];
    NSString *dateString2 = [DateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    lbl.text = dateString2;
    return dateString2;
}
```

Comment: I know how the conversion is done, what I am not getting is the "date format" that has to be set. I have tried setting 
"yyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZZZ" also

Comment: is not `"yyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZZZ"`it is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I checked in playground, even this is not working

Comment: I agree with @Anbu.Karthik. It is correct format  yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik added the image with question please see